# How to make a function that, after pressing the pause button, resumes the audio automatically after 3 seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a simple page, that has audio on autoplay. It also has a "pause" and "play" button. I want to create a function that, when you press the "pause" button, the audio will stop; but after 3 seconds the audio will resume to its current reproduction mark.

Like an **if** function that when you press the "pause" button, the audio stops, but after a delay of e.g. 3 seconds the "play" button is pressed automatically. (That's how I imagine it could work, but I don't have the knowledge)

This is my **HTML**

```
<audio id="player" src="audio/song.mp3"  loop></audio>

<div>
<button class="play" onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">Play</button>
<button class="pausa" onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()">||</button></div>
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm new. I will delete this immediately.

Comment: @Damon You cannot ask how to write a function because there is no one way to do so and answers will get too long and wordy. Yes, you can ask why your attempt failed but that's not what is being asked here.

Comment: More importantly **DON'T DO THIS**. Whether to play audio shoud be left to the users' discretion.. **especially if they have specifically turned it off**.

Comment: @Rob I don't follow. If an answer is too long and wordy, that could just be a bad answer and will get downvoted. I don't see multiple solutions as a bad thing assuming they are valid, and are actually doing different things.

Comment: @Damon Thank you! I'll check it out.

Comment: @Paulie_D That isn't a problem, is just a page for a few users that want that feature. (Yes, I understand is annoying and against UX principles) Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally may not agree with the decision of resuming a paused media automatically after *n* seconds. But for pure technical understanding I will share how I would do that.

Building on top of what you already have, you can have multiple commands on onClick separated by semi-colon. Adding setTimeout() function call to play after 3000 ms (3 seconds):

```
<button class="pausa" onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause(); setTimeout(document.getElementById('player').play(), 3000)">||</button>
```

Of course it would be better if you move all your code to a function and just call that function onclick. This way you can have more code without making html/view unreadable and crowded. Like this:

Edit: I corrected a typo: "paseNplay()" instead of "pauseNplay()" . Now it works perfectly!

```
<button class="pausa" onclick="pauseNplay()">||</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function pauseNplay(){
   var player = document.getElementById('player');
   player.pause(); 
   setTimeout(function(){ player.play() }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but now the "pause" button doesn't pause the audio. Perhaps some typo mistake? This is my code now.

`<audio id="player" src="audio/song.mp3"   loop></audio>`

`<div>
 <button class="play" onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">Play</button>
  <!--<button class="pausa" onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()">||</button>-->
  <button class="pausa" onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause(); setTimeout(document.getElementById('player').play(), 3000)">||</button>
</div> `

Comment: I have updated the answer with an example of a separate function. Comment out the setTimeout() line to make sure your pause is working first. Then uncomment and test.

Comment: Try setTimeout(function(){ player.play() }, 3000) otherwise play() gets executed before the timeout

Comment: Good suggestion @emed. I've updated the code, thanks.